# "Thread was being aborted" in WCF Service Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf, prtg

In my program there is a aspx page that contains wcf client, that so on calls wcf service located on same server.

I`v get this exception when my wcf client calls wcf service hosted in IIS on production server.

Ex. msg:  `Thread was being aborted.`

Ex stack:

> at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.recv(IntPtr socketHandle,
>   Byte* pinnedBuffer, Int32 len, SocketFlags socketFlags)   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags, SocketError& errorCode)   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest
>   request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)   at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult
>   returnResult)   at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.CallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ResubmitWrite(ConnectStream oldStream,
>   Boolean suppressWrite)   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndWriteHeaders_Part2()   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndWriteHeaders(Boolean async)   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteHeadersCallback(WebExceptionStatus
>   errorStatus, ConnectStream stream, Boolean async)   at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndSubmitRequest()   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)   at
>   StationService.IStationService.GetCurrentStationTrack(String
>   stationId)   at
>   StationService.StationServiceClient.GetCurrentStationTrack(String
>   stationId)   at GetSongJS.getMarq(String radioIdentifier)

I using PRTG Ipmonitor and it give me too many requests on "Requests Current" sensor.
My site becomes anavailable in browser.
If a delete this page that calls service all is going to be OK.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you are not closing the WCF client.

What I think is happening is:

- User calls the aspx page
- aspx page calls the service
- aspx page returns to the user
- the service client is not closed, therefore request is open and number of current requests is high
- eventually you have the max number of requests open
- the page waits for a free connection, when it does not get one the aspx page timesout
- you then get a thread abort exception from the timeout

Answer (score 2):

Is there a `Response.Redirect(url)` call after the client proxy makes its call? The single argument overload will terminate the current thread which leads to many of these types of errors showing up in logs. Sometimes the page has finished working and it doesn't happen, but switching to another busier environment is often a trigger.

Comment: No there is not any Response.Redirect(url) in that page. There are just Page_Load which calls methos that creats client proxy, then calls its method and get result from him.